# Testing the FileReader API using a test run by node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, phantomjs, fileapi

I'm looking for a way to experiment with the file reader API in a node test ([REFERENCE - Reading files in JavaScript using the File APIs](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/).).

I'd like to be able to run a node test that automates the experimentation.  Something like:

`> node test.js` which would simulate file selection and read the file...the semantics should be the same as if I had selected a file using a browser button and read the file using the corresponding handler ... thoughts?

Comment: what is the point? you're testing a simulation, not a browser...

Comment: Wheres the connection between user code and server testing? I dont get it...

Comment: I'd like to for example test the onerror handling when an non existant file is passed to the API ...